# proper http status to refuse client view image with invalid referrer page

Tags: permissions, http

Short version: If I decide to reject access to some URI because a client doesn't supply a valid Referer HTTP header, what http status do I response?

Long: Suppose I wrote a blog post with very nice photos. I want my visitors share with their friends by using a link to this blog post, but am a little sad if my visitors share with their friends with a link directly to the image files bypassing my blog post. Besides persuading in words like “please share with your friends with a link to this blog post”, what is a polite way to indicate that the images files are better accessed with corresponding HTTP Referer header by using a certain http status?

Answer (score 2):

There is no status-code officially dedicated to this (very common) situation and using 400 is wrong ([400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) means, the server does not understand the request, which is not true).

Depending on your persuasions, you can:

- Reply with a [301](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/301) redirecting to your blog page -- this would cause your images to fail to appear on other people's pages, but folks trying to open them explicitly would be redirected to your page
- Reply with a 301 to a special image showing, for example, a big red X with a text explaining your position
- Reply with a [403 Unauthorized](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) which means exactly, what you want: *I understand, what you are asking for, but will not give it to you*
- Reply with something more esoteric like [417 Expectation failed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/417) or [418 Don't you be no teapot](https://httpstatuses.com/418) :-)

Be sure to include the brief explanation in the body of your response -- and a link to your blog...

Answer (score 0):

To do this, there is no special http response. Typically use *400 "Bad Request"* or *444 "Connection Closed Without Response"*